# Changing the second order tansfer function to the standard form

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, linear

I want to change this second order transfer function to the standard form to obtain tp, Mp and,...how can i change this to standard form? [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's certainly not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: In standard form which you wrote ,you miss   a term k (also known as gain ) in numerator and its value is 2/3in your question

Comment: Can you write that please?

Comment: 2/3×[15/(s^2+s+15)]

Comment: I did, actually i just  want to get the standard form and obtain other things on my own, @TonyM

Comment: But it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. You leave behind fully-formed questions that are useful to future readers. From this and your other questions, you appear to be using the site for the few details you want, leaving behind you incomplete and cryptic questions.

Answer (score 1):

Standard form is \$G(s)=\large\frac{K_{ss}\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta \omega_n s+\omega_n^2}\$, where \$\small K_{ss}\$ is the steady state gain.

Comment: Does kss effect on peak time or zeta or wn? Or on peak time value(c(tp))?

Comment: Only affects the final value in response to a step input. Settling time, time to 1st peak,  percentage overshoot etc are all unaffected by Kss.